# Magento 2 Braintree paypal not working

Tags: magento2.3, onepage-checkout, payment-methods, paypal, braintree

Magento 2 Braintree Paypal is not working when we click on the PayPal radio button then it shows popup after entering details like email and password we can see our details on PayPal popup window when we click on continue then popup close and show checkout page(please refer to screenshot) with email instead of going to the success page.

[image]